# Explanation of while loop with no body

Tags: android

Came across this solution during development of messaging app. My problem was that the download URL of the profile image was not saving as an actual URL in my firebase database, but this solution worked.

My problem is that I can not understand the use of the while loop.

I understand how the loop works, keeps repeating until `task.isSuccessful()` returns `true`, but I do not understand why it was used as such.

```
filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


           Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
           while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
           Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();

           final String sdownload_url = String.valueOf(downloadUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onSuccessListener()` is probably called on a separate thread. What this code is doing is basically starting a new task in from that thread that gets the download url:

```
 Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
```

Now in your onSuccessListener, you need the download url but in order to get the download url, above task has to complete. `DownloadUrl` task is running on a separate thread. So, **the loop is *blocking* your `onSuccessListener` until the downloadUrl is fetched**.

```
 while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
 //Won't reach this line until above task is successful
 final String sdownload_url = String.valueOf(downloadUrl);
```

This will keep returning false until the download url is fetched. When the task is completed, `isSuccessful` returns true and the `onSuccessListener` can move on to the next statement.

**NOTE**:
This is not a good approach to your problem. If your app *fails* to fetch the download url, your loop will go on forever as well as your onSuccessListener thread.

Instead, add a success listener to your downloadUrl task and put the lines below your loop in that success listener. It doesn't necessarily has to be nested. You can create a success listener in your outer class and reference it inside the success listener you already have.

Answer (score 0):

The Task class is used for asynchronous execution of tasks which may have external dependency. Since it is asynchronous, you have to process the results after detecting task states like success, failure, error etc.
In case of Task class it can be done by polling ( i.e. calling getResult method) which will block further execution of the rest of the program which is in this case, or by using a listener which will not block execution but will invoke the listener callback method on task events. See addOnCompleteListener method in the documentation : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task